# Tables according to APA format

Tags: tables, apa-style

I am currently working on a seminar paper, but I am stuck with the creation of tables according to APA (American Psychological Association).

At the moment, I am stuck with two issues. 
First, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to create a table as seen below. Therefore, I am happy for any kind of advice from your crowd intelligence. [image: Desired table structure]

Second, I have created the following correlation table, which is way too long. I am interested in the inter-item correlation of 30 items. My problem is that the correlation coefficients do not fit onto one page. Do you guys have any suggestions as to how I can modify the table to still give a nice overview?

Thanks a lot.

```
\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3, table-number-alignment=center}
\small
\null\vfill
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{longtable}{l*{30}{S}}
        \caption{Cross-correlation table\label{corrtable}}\\
        \toprule\midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variablen} &{(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} &{(7)} & {(8)} & {(9)} & {(10)} & {(11)}&{(12)}&{(13)}&{(14)}&{(15)}&{(16)}&{(17)}&{(18)}&{(19)}&{(20)}&{(21)}&{(22)}&{(23)}&{(24)}&{(25)}&{(26)}&{(27)}&{(28)}&{(29)}&{(30)}\\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{\emph{... table \thetable{} continued}}
        \\ \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variables} &{ Investments} & {\makecell{Cross-\\border}} & {Domestic} & {Early} & {GDP} & { \makecell{Market\\ Cap.}} &{ CPI} & {PRS} & {AS} & {IPO} & {Sales}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page...}}\\
        \endfoot
        \midrule\bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        Investments & 1.000\\
        Cross-border & 0.885 & 1.000\\
        Domestic & 0.571 & 0.122 & 1.000\\
        Early & 0.758 & 0.849 & 0.118 & 1.000\\
        GDP & 0.168 & 0.073 & 0.230 & 0.072 & 1.000\\
        Market Cap. & 0.012 & -0.019 & 0.059 & 0.013 & -0.182 & 1.000\\
        CPI & 0.195 & 0.107 & 0.227 & 0.088 & 0.096 & 0.008 & 1.000\\
        PRS & 0.133 & 0.099 & 0.110 & 0.102 & 0.088 & -0.085 & 0.695 & 1.000\\
        AS & -0.201 & -0.074 & -0.298 & -0.028 & -0.172 & -0.072 & -0.522 & -0.442 & 1.000\\
        IPO & 0.077 & -0.038 & 0.231 & 0.004 & 0.038 & 0.131 & 0.178 & 0.020 & -0.011 & 1.000\\
        Sales & 0.126 & 0.060 & 0.163 & -0.001 & 0.139 & -0.175 & 0.373 & 0.312 & -0.379 & 0.026 & 1.000\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
```

The variables on the y-axis should be the same as on the x-axis (item01, item02 etc.) but I haven't modified it yet, since the items do not fit onto one page. Right now, it looks like this:
[image: Cross-correlation table]

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: And always post full minimal examples, not sniplets like this. Now we have to get the rest in order to even test your code.

Comment: Whiche \documentclass do you use?

Comment: @leandriis Ok, sorry for that.

Comment: @Bernard I am using the article documentclass

Comment: Can you  consider changing the default margins (if you don't use marginal notes)? Do you use the a4paper  option or the default letterpaper or whatever?

Comment: @bernard I think this won't change a lot. I am using the a4 paper option, btw.

Comment: Could you split your table in half? You could present the correlation of all 30 rows with the first 15 columns in the first table and the other half in a second table? If the table is still too wide, probably splitting into thirds might work.